# How to convert magento 1.x module to magento 2.x module

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, upgrade, model

I need to convert my modules from 1.9.X to 2.0.X,

Is there any way to convert, or we will start from scratch.?

Answer (score 3):

Although, I have not tried it before, but there are some scripts available which claim that they can convert Magento 1.x modules to Magento 2.x modules.

Below are some reference links:

https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2

Since folder structure and coding pattern are totally different between Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x, one can not use Magento 1.x modules directly into Magento 2.x, but there is an official code migration tool which can help the developers to migrate theirs modules and design themes:

https://github.com/magento/code-migration

But the tools is for experienced developers only.

Comment: should i directly upload the magento 1.x extension to magento 2 ?

Comment: No, since both versions are not directly compatible with each other, you are advised to convert extension to appropriate version of Magento before uploading it.

Comment: How to convert extension to appropriate version of Magento before uploading?

Comment: In my answer, I have posted some help links.

Comment: i want to convert the following magento 1.x module to magento 2 https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bongo-international.html

Comment: I have noted the help links you provided. But my doubt is where i should execute the code-migration codes. I have upload these codes in magento1 or magento 2?

Comment: For https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2, there are installation instructions under **`Installation and Usage`** section. Please check it once and let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Now i understood the procedure. I will try and let you know.. Thanks for your support..

Comment: @MohitKumarArora -  Bongo International has been acquired by FedEx and relaunched as "FedEx CrossBorder". I would enquire with FedEx before putting much effort into rewriting code. They may have something available for Magento2.

Comment: OK @g-man1066, please check and share your findings so that others can also get benefit from your efforts.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora - I do business with them on a daily basis.... 
[link] (http://about.van.fedex.com/newsroom/global-english/fedex-introduces-global-e-commerce-solutions-under-fedex-crossborder/)

Answer (score 0):

Bongo International has been acquired by FedEx and relaunched as "FedEx CrossBorder". [FedEx Introduces Global E-Commerce Solutions Under FedEx CrossBorder](http://about.van.fedex.com/newsroom/global-english/fedex-introduces-global-e-commerce-solutions-under-fedex-crossborder/)

I would enquire with FedEx before putting much effort into rewriting code. They may have something available for Magento2.

Comment: did you find any extension related to this FedEx Cross Border - Bongo ?

Comment: Yes. They have released the CrossBorder extension for Magento 2. Talk to your sales rep or technical contact you'll need credentials, etc. to make it work. I think the extension is also available for download from the Marketplace.